# Setting Python GRPC client socket options

Tags: grpc, setsockopt, grpc-python

I am looking at a way to set socket options in grpc python.

Scenario: I am running a GRPC client on a host with multiple interfaces and routes defined per interface, called VRF (Virtual Routing and Forwarding). My application has to bind to a specific interface for which I have to call setsockopt with SO_BINDTODEVICE option. If I don't set the option socket is bound to a default interface where the destination is not reachable due to routes set on that the interface. The interface(VRF) has to be picked from external configuration and setsockopt on that value and use this configured value while binding the socket. So is there a way to access  GRPC client sockets once we create insecure_channel?